# How can I make Xcode load the right string.h file?

Tags: c, xcode

I've inherited a bunch of folders with C files in them, and I'm supposed to make a library of them in Xcode for an iOS project. I have no prior C experience, although I've coded in Obj-C.

But the library does not compile in Xcode, and the issue appears to be that the previous coder has named a file `gu/string.h`. When, then, one of the files tries to include `string.h` from the standard library, Xcode chooses the first one instead.

The same code compiles fine on OSX (through the terminal), on Ubuntu, even on Windows, and `.i` files on those systems show that the inclusions are handled correctly.

Is there any way I can force Xcode to look for the files in the order I want it to? If not, I'll rename the file and fix the include directives - naming a file the same as a standard library file seems very trololo anyway - but I'd prefer to keep the code I got intact if possible.

Comment: you can put them in two different bundles and load them as and when required.

Comment: The only real solution here is to change the file name.  There's no excuse to name a file the same as on in the standard library.  There might be a work-around, but is it worth it?  What happens when the next Xcode patch reverses the fix, and it's not you, but some OTHER programmer that now has to deal with it?  Had you just renamed the file, it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: And it's not that absurd to assume Xcode might unfix some workaround like this.

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, you definitely have a point. I sure wasn't happy to spend hours searching for what turned out to be a really stupid problem.

Comment: @nhgrif, the problem isn't the name collision, it's the lack of a path. Had they imported `gu/string.h`, this wouldn't have been a problem. There's no reason that you have to carefully avoid every system file name that exists or might exist in the future. You just have to use paths. Just like ObjC prefixes; you're crazy to name something `NSTree` even though there is no such thing currently in Cocoa. But it's perfectly fine to name something `MYXString` even though there is an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution isn't to fix the name, but the include path. The best path is relative to SRCROOT (to top of your tree):

```
#import "somepackage/gu/string.h"
```

For some trees that's awkward, so you can set the Header Search Paths to include the directory that has `gu` in it. Then use:

```
#import "gu/string.h"
```

If that's not possible, you can add the whole path to User Header Search Paths and just make sure to use quotes rather than brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd rather not modify the files if possible. Right now, they use angle brackets, and all other files import correctly through the header search paths. Changing all of the import directives in every file would be a lot more work than just renaming this specific file.

Comment: Using "#import <string.h>" to mean "import a non-system header" is definitely going to cause you headaches as you've discovered. Renaming the file is probably the best you can do, but it's poor C practice. It's ok to use brackets with a path for a third-party thing (<gu/string.h>) and it can be reasonable to use quotes without a path (though I don't recommend it), but brackets without a path causes exactly this kind of problem, having nothing to do with it happening to be named "string".

Comment: I realise this reply is very late, but I've given your answer and other comments some thoughts and I agree with what you're saying. Thank you for the input!

Comment: I have exactly same problem but I don't understand the answer. I have include/core/String.h which is included as `#include "core/String.h"`. When standard /usr/include/string.h is included it uses `#include <string.h>`. This works everywhere (cross-platform) except when used in XCode - using brackets without `core` path still loads my String.h instead of standard string.h. How can I include standard string.h without having collision? The search path is set to include (contains core/String.h) and is not marked as recursive.